# Sort map by key string (where key is actually an integer)

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am trying to sort a map to show in a dropdown. But I am not able to get any sorting done. This will return a new map. But not with the map sorted by the key as I would expect.

```
private Map<String, String> mapInstrumentIDs = new TreeMap<>();

Map<Object, Object> val = mapInstrumentIDs
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I of course didn't think about that the key is actually an integer. This means sorting it as a string does not give me the expected result (as integer sort). Changing the key to Integer and converting the value will yield the expected result.

Comment: You don't need to sort `mapInstrumentIDs`. It's a `TreeMap`, so it implicitly sorts its entries by key.

Comment: can you paste your input and your expected output?

Comment: what makes you think that the map returned by .collect() is going to be sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/TreeMap.html) guarantees that its elements will be sorted in ascending key order.

Answer (score 3):

You should collect the results into a `Map` implementation that retains the order of its entries.  `LinkedHashMap` will do:

```
Map<String, String> sorted = mapInstrumentIDs.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, 
            Map.Entry::getValue, 
            (x,y)-> {throw new AssertionError();},
            LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Comment: Of course, if the intended order is being sorted by keys, a `TreeMap` will retain the order smoothly. Then we get, what the OP has before trying to sort the already sorted data…

Comment: I suspect this is a case of questioner not pasting the real code and he is not actually using a `TreeMap` or his `TreeMap` is using a `Comparator` other than natural ordering.  Or maybe he wants to avoid O(log(n)) lookups of `TreeMap`.

Comment: Still, creating a map sorted by keys in natural order is as simple as `new TreeMap<>(oldMap)`, insert a typecast to `Map` if `oldMap` happens to be a `SortedMap` having a different order (which I doubt). And yes, the question makes no sense…

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would make a copy as:

```
private SortedMap<String, String> mapInstrumentIDs = new TreeMap<>();
SortedMap<String, String> val = new TreeMap(mapInstrumentIDs);
```

If you want a copy with key type `Comparable<?>` and value type `Object`, you want to specify the initial map as TreeMap and cannot use the standard collectors:

```
SortedMap<Comparable, Object> val = mapInstrumentIDs
                .entrySet()
                .collect(TreeMap<Comparable, Object>::new,
                    (m, e) -> { m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()); return m; },
                    (m, m2) -> m.addAll(m2)
                );
```

Comment: **Don’t** use `reduce` for mutable data structures! A `TreeMap` that you are going to modify is not an identity value. Use [`collect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) for a [Mutable reduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction)

Comment: @Holger you are right; changed it, as that is FP pure.